# Equivalence of Limits

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a function $c(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} c(x) = 0$ would the following two limits be equivalent:

$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(c(x))$

Assuming $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists. If yes, does c(x) have to have any special properties in order for this to hold

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition of limits:

Let $\lim_{x\to 0} c(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{y\to 0} f(y) = L$, then

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(c(x)) = 0$$

if, either:

1. $f$ is continuous at $0$, or
2. There exists an open, deleted neighborhood $N$ around $x=0$ such that $c(x) ≠ 0$ for all $x \in N$.

We need either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions $c$ and $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to0} c(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=L$, yet $\lim_{x\to0} f(c(x))$ does not exist.

For example: let
$$f(x)=\cases{1&if $x\ne0$\cr 2&if $x=0$,\cr}$$
and let $c(x)$ be a function that approaches $0$, taking both zero and non-zero values infinitely often, for example,
$$c(x)=x\sin\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)$$
for $x\ne0$, with $c(0)=0$.  Then $\lim_{x\to0} c(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=1$.  However
$$f(c(x))=\cases{2&if $x=0$ or $x=1/n\pi$\cr 1&otherwise,\cr}$$
which has no limit as $x\to0$.

If $f$ were continuous at $0$ then we would have $\lim_{x\to0} f(c(x))=L$.